# Weblogic Authentication LDAP retrieve information from the user

Tags: java, spring, authentication, ldap, weblogic

My architecture :

- An open LDAP where I have my users and my groups
- A weblogic connected to this LDAP
- A Spring application using the weblogic authentication

My problem is the following : I have only the username that tries to connect at UserDetailsService implementation level in the loadUserByUsername method (if the connection is a success).
I would like to have groups associated to this user in the LDAP.

I can write another call to the LDAP, but I would like, for performance, know if it is possible to get these information through the first call to the LDAP ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: LDAP normal flow is to bind (to validate authenticity of user supplied credentials) first followed by **next** search operation for fetching user details (including group information). As such, the search call is necessary in case your application relies upon LDAP server for user info (instead of local database). Having said that, it's very common practice to cache (with time based eviction) LDAP user information. If not provided by weblogic, you can create a cache wrapper yourself using [spring cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer first :D
So you mean that the authenticity validating doesn't fetch user details ?
And we need to make another call to the LDAP after to fetch all details ?

Comment: "_ ..authenticity validating doesn't fetch user details ?_" - Correct. "_we need to make another call to the LDAP after to fetch all details_" - Correct again.